# Where can we see the whole list of named language values?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, multilingual, cultureinfo

I notice that we can set the language for a form by using `Xml:lang="en-US"`. I want to see the named of other languages but not sure where those can be accessed from C#.

Please help.

**Edit**
I prefer to know an enum type which list the value set. Is there one available? Or we have to create that ourselves?

Since it seems to be no available enum type for this, [here](http://db.tt/SlVI7qF) is my own-created one.

Comment: Perhaps this page might be useful? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745650.aspx#design_intl_ui_with_xaml

Comment: Actually these aren't languages but they're called 'cultures'.

Comment: @Gerrie: en-US is a "culture" or "locale": it defines both a language ("en") and a region ("US").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see a list of the other culture you can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

For .NET cultures belonging to a specific country and region:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
```

To access all the .NET cultures (standard or not), use:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
```

Answer (score 4):

To get all valid culture infos:

```
CultureInfo[] cultureInfos = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
```

Maybe you need this:

```
string xmlCulture = "en-US";
bool isSupported = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).Any(c => c.Name.Equals(xmlCulture));
```